# Adding a telephone extension socket

Tags: telephone, phone-wiring

I have recently moved into a new apartment and I have rewired a couple of phone sockets as the had clearly been messed with before. While decorating I removed a blanking plate in the living room and found phone wires behind. I believe this might have been an optional upgrade when the flat was built, but they obviously wired them anyway and just put the socket on.

Behind this plate are 2 wires. One has a white sheath and looks like all the others in the flat. The other has a grey sheath and is different. As far as I can tell this is the last socket in the chain.

Where could the grey one go?

Comment: How many wires are in each set? It sounds like you might have a Cat3(24/6) and a Cat5e(24/8) wire. Can you post a picture?

Comment: From memory 4 or 5 twisted pairs. This is the only socket with the different wire. I'll try and take a photo later

Comment: I have wired the socket into the white sheathed wire and my router has an internet connection. They were both 4 pair

Comment: They're both Cat5e then (which is more common of late). So sounds like one is being used as Ethernet then.